# How to tell YASnippet to ignore placeholder?

Tags: yasnippet

I have a shell script which uses an array to check dependencies. I'd like to make this into a YASnippet, but YAS recognizes the array value statement `${dependencies[@]}` as a placeholder. How can I tell YAS to ignore this placeholder?

```
# key: write.bash
# name: write.bash
# --
#!/bin/bash

dependencies=("${1:dependency 1}" "${2:dependency 2}")

for i in ${dependencies[@]}; do
if [ "$(which $i)" = "" ] ; then
    echo "EARLY EXIT- $i needs to be installed and on PATH"
    exit 0
    else
    echo "$i installed"
fi;
done
```

Comment: I can tab through the placeholder and get the correct syntax using: 
`$${3:{dependencies[@]}}`
but I would like to avoid the placeholder altogether

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\` to escape `$` in `${dependencies[@]}`, as noted [here](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#org0e7ccf8).
The complete snippet is below:

```
# key: write.bash
# name: write.bash
# --
#!/bin/bash

dependencies=("${1:dependency 1}" "${2:dependency 2}")

for i in \${dependencies[@]}; do
if [ "$(which $i)" = "" ] ; then
    echo "EARLY EXIT- $i needs to be installed and on PATH"
    exit 0
    else
    echo "$i installed"
fi;
done
```